# How to limit access to slim 4 endpoint to allow only browser extensions ajax requests

Tags: php, heroku, google-chrome-extension, slim, browser-extension

I'v created an api service using heroku and php for my chrome extensions. I want to limit it's usage only to chrome extensions but at the moment I have no idea of how to proceed, I'm considering the identity api to limit some functions only to logged in users but on heroku I don't have a database so my question is, what is the best way to restrict access to the endpoints if they are not called from the `chrome://` context? I'm running two different services using a single slim 4 instance and I'm worried to cause problem also to the endpoint that can be accessed publicy without restriction.

Comment: For as long as you run your tests when you make the requests from the Chrome plugin, did you debug the request headers? Maybe you have some information that could help you determine if the request comes from a Chrome extension or from a standard HTTP Request. Other than that, what about using a static access key hardcoded in the source code of your Chrome plugin? I know, it's the best idea, as a reverse engineering could reveal the API key, but if the API isn't so important, I guess you could use it.

Comment: As I know, there is no particular information that is send to the server when ajax requests are made from a chrome extension. I'm thinking to add tha access control header on server with `chrome://` protocol but I'm not sure if this will broke my endpoints due to the fact that each extension has it's own unique id.  The api key is another solution, but in this case I want to release it to the user only if he request it after login with identity api, hardcode the key isn't a reilable way for the services I'm implementing

Comment: did you thought of the Firebase solution? You could have a database, as well as server side logic for free.

Comment: I'm thinking about using firestore, but I need to understand how to integrate it in server logics to work with slim 4